# How to extract temperature decimal value from a Bluetooth LE (SIG) hex value

Tags: xamarin.android, bluetooth-lowenergy

I'm developing a xamarin android app to connect to a bluetooth low energy thermometer.
I can already connect and read its value. My problem is that it's in hexadecimal format and i haven't found a way to extract its value in a decimal (celsius) format.

Here's some sample readings:

- For 36.0 celsius i got 06-68-01-00-FF-E2-07-03-0A-15-34-00-02
- For 36.2 celsius i got 06-6A-01-00-FF-E2-07-03-0A-14-14-00-02
- For 36.8 celsius i got 06-70-01-00-FF-E2-07-03-0A-14-1B-00-02
- For 34.6 celsius i got 06-5A-01-00-FF-E2-07-03-0A-14-1F-00-02

From what i understand, it must be the 2º "column" above (hexadecimal values 68, 6A, 70, 5A). The values in the 10º and 11º "columns" seams to be related to  measurement time (hh-mm).

How can i extract the value? 
Is there a generic formula i can use? 
Is there a way to know it's unit of measure so i can convert to celsius (if it isn't already)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

"My problem is that it's in hexadecimal format".
I'm sure that you received a byte-array, you just read or printed it in hexadecimal format.

To get something useful, you have to get the relevant data from the original byte array.

`06-68-01-00-FF-E2-07-03-0A-15-34-00-02` is `[6,104,1,0,255,226,7,3,10,21,52,0,2]`.

The first byte (byte[0] = 6) is a bit-flag: `00000110`.

- Bit 0 is the most right = `0` , meaning Temperature Measurement Value in units of Celsius. (if 1 Fahrenheit).
- Bit 1 = `1`, means Time Stamp field is present. `0` if Time Stamp field not present.
- Bit 2 = `1`, means Temperature Type field is present. `0` if Temperature Type field not present.

All other bits are not relevant, they are reserved for future use.

- Bytes[1] (104) and [2] (1) is the temperature as FLOAT in Celsius * 10. To get the temp multiply byte[2] by 256 and add byte[1], divide total by 10.
  result: 1 * 256 + 104 = 360. Temperature is 36.0
- Bytes3 and 4 have no meaning here. normally they are part of the 4 byte  temperature float.
- Bytes [5] (226) and [6] (7) is the Year as INT16: 7 * 256 + 226 = 2018.
- Byte[7] (3) is the month. 0 meaning unknown, 1 = January , here 3 = March.
- Byte[8] (10) is the day of the month, here 10.
- Byte[10] (21) is the Hour(Number of hours past midnight), here 21.
- Byte[11] (52) is the Minute, here 52.
- Byte[12] (0) is the Second, here 0.
- Byte[13] (2) is the Temperature Type, here Body (general). Other options for this byte are:

````
1   Armpit
2   Body (general)
3   Ear (usually ear lobe)
4   Finger
5   Gastro-intestinal Tract
6   Mouth
7   Rectum
8   Toe
9   Tympanum (ear drum)
10 - 255    Reserved for future use
0   Reserved for future use```
````

Comment: Where do you get the info? The [temperature characteristic XML](https://www.bluetooth.com/wp-content/uploads/Sitecore-Media-Library/Gatt/Xml/Characteristics/org.bluetooth.characteristic.temperature_measurement.xml) only provide the bit definition for the first byte. Is this 13 bytes a standard or proprietary definition? Some provides different [definition](https://www.silabs.com/community/wireless/bluetooth/forum.topic.html/temperature_measurem-1FiO)

Answer (score 2):

(I cannot comment on GrooverFromHolland's answer due to not enough reputation so so this is my answer here where at least some of the information can be found)

It might be interesting to add, that this FLOAT is **NOT** a 32bit single precision float (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-precision_floating-point_format)
but a 32 bit float for medical devices defined by **IEEE 11073-20601**. See **chapter 2.2.1** for the float definition here:

https://www.bluetooth.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/03/PHD_Transcoding_WP_v16.pdf

So basically you have to do this:

```
temperature_float = mantissa * 10 ^ exponent

where
exponent is an 8 bit (signed) int value
mantissa is a 24 bit (signed) int value
```

So let's take your bytes 1...4 which contain the temperature values (from 0x06-**68-01-00-FF**-E2-07-03-0A-15-34-00-02):

```
"Temperature" bytes 
0x68-01-00-FF

0xFF is the exponent (Bluetooth data comes in LSB first, so you have to flip the bytes)
exponent = 0xFF     (hex)
         = 11111111 (bin)
           ^
           sign bit is set => negative number
         = -1       (int8, two's complement)

mantissa = 0x00-01-68 (again flipped because Bluetooth data comes LSB first)
         = 00000000-00000001-01101000
           ^
           sign bit is not set => positive number
         = 360 (int24, two's complement)

So your temperature will then be 
temperature_float = 360 * (10^-1) = 36.0°C
```

Some more details can be found here
https://www.bluetooth.com/specifications/specs/health-thermometer-service-1-0/
For example the flag byte (0x06 = 00000110) which was nicely described by GrooverFromHolland is explained in chapters 3.1.1.1 ... 3.1.1.4.

Answer (score 0):

The specification for the temperature characteristic can be found here:
https://www.bluetooth.com/specifications/gatt/viewer?attributeXmlFile=org.bluetooth.characteristic.temperature_measurement.xml

So basically the temperature value is a float spanning 4 bytes.

Comment: They removed the viewer :( the xml is confusing AF

Comment: the link is broken could you please update

Answer (score 0):

These data come from the Bluetooth specs, depending on the service you need to use, in this case the service is the temperature. The information is written inside the xml file of the service specification. See the following link for temperature, it is from Bluetooth.com

[see temperature service here](https://www.bluetooth.com/wp-content/uploads/Sitecore-Media-Library/Gatt/Xml/Characteristics/org.bluetooth.characteristic.temperature_measurement.xml)

Another explanation exist in this link.
[See the solution in this link for details](https://www.silabs.com/community/wireless/bluetooth/forum.topic.html/temperature_measurem-1FiO)

The following link has a list of many xml files of the services used in bluetooth. I am adding it for reference.
[many xml services here](https://github.com/sputnikdev/bluetooth-gatt-parser/tree/master/src/main/resources/gatt/characteristic)