# How to get the correct temperature value from byte array

Tags: java, android, bluetooth-lowenergy

I'm trying to create a BLE app where i want to catch the value of the temperature from a device. I'm using Temp Sitter device.

I have this UUID=0000ffe1-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb. From here I get an array of bytes.

```java
// For all other profiles, writes the data formatted in HEX.
final byte[] data = characteristic.getValue();

if (data != null && data.length > 0) {
    final StringBuilder stringBuilder = new 
                                       StringBuilder(data.length);
    for(byte byteChar : data)
        stringBuilder.append(String.format("%02X ", byteChar));
    intent.putExtra(EXTRA_DATA, new String(data) + "\n" + 
    stringBuilder.toString());
}
```

Here are some hex results:

```
AA 06 11 00 3E 0D 00 62 --- 
AA 06 11 00 43 0D 00 67 --- 
AA 06 11 00 49 0D 00 6D
```

Can any one help me how to read the exact value of this array?

Comment: Most likely, the device sends the data in a binary format. Please add the hexadecimal result of your current code to your question. Most likley you want something like `double temp = data[3] / 100.0 + data[2];`

Comment: I try it but i have the same value all the time 17.0:  TEMPERATUREEE 17.0 for this hex value  AA 06 11 00 3E 0D 00 62  ----- TEMPERATUREEE 17.0 also for this hex value  AA 06 11 00 3E 0D 00 62

Comment: if your final result is to show the values of byte array just like string, then i would suggest you to use stringbuilder. Iterate over byte array and append each values to stringbuilder and finally use stringbuilder to show value.

Comment: There doesn't seem to be any documentation about the protocol the sensor uses. So we have to reverse engineer it. Can you make temperature measurements at three rather different temperatures (such 20, 30 and 40 deg C) and add both the approximate temperature as well as the data you get from the sensor?

Comment: see the following question and it is answered there
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54829004/how-to-extract-temperature-decimal-value-from-a-bluetooth-le-sig-hex-value

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to extract temperature decimal value from a Bluetooth LE (SIG) hex value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54829004/how-to-extract-temperature-decimal-value-from-a-bluetooth-le-sig-hex-value)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After reverse-engineering the IRULU / Guangdong Biolight Meditech *Temp Sitter* app, it looks as if the message has this format:

```
            0      1      2      3      4      5      6      7
        +------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+
        |Marker|Length|Type  |Subtyp|Low   |High  |Unused|Chksum|
        +------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+

Example    AA     06     11     00     3E     0D     00     62
```

The fields are:

- *Marker*: Always 0xAA. Marker used to delinate message. The message format seems to be designed to send a stream of messages. 0xAA would indicate the start of a new message.
- *Length*: The payload length, in bytes. It's the length without marker and without checksum.
- *Type*: The type of the message. 0x11 seem to be temperature messages. There's also a message tpe 0x12 that seems interesting (even though I don't understand its purpose). Other message types are ignored by the app.
- *Subtype*: The message subtype. Subtype 0 are temperature measurements. Subtype 1 and 2 seems to *high* and *low* warnings/indicators.
- *Low*: The low byte of the temperature value.
- *High*: The high byte of the temperature value.
- *Unused*: This byte seems to be unsued and set to 0.
- *Checksum*: The checksum of the payload. It is simply computed by adding all bytes of the payload (starting with *length* and ending with the *unused* field).

The temperature value is stored in 0.01 degree (probably degree Celsius). So to extract it, you compute:

```
double temperature = ((message[5] & 0xff) * 256 + (message[4] & 0xff)) * 0.01;
```

In the above example, the result would be 33.90 °C.

Comment: In this formula what's this 256 multiplier means? Can you explain the purpose of using 256 there and its origin?

Comment: @TechyTee The value is split into two bytes. Each byte can have a value from 0 to 255. So it was split by dividing the value by 256, putting the integer result (quotient) into one byte and the remainder into the other byte. To join them, the operation must be undone: multiply the quotient with 256 and add the remainder.